# Paperclip Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /system)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My production environment is : ruby 1.9.2-p320 , rails 3.2.7, paperclip 3.1.4, mysql, Ubuntu 8.10 x86 64bit.

I have a Errno:EACCES Permission denied /system error when i try to upload a file with paperclip. Useless to say that locally this doesn't happen.
I checked the public directory permissions and it's 775, the public/system permission is 777 as well as all it's inner directory. The tmp directory permission is : 775 too.
Moreover the user used to deploy the application is www-data:root

The model's attachment is set like this :

```
has_attached_file :fichier,
        :path => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
        :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

I can't find out why i get this error. Anyone has got an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code DOES NOT try to save the uploaded file in:

```
/path/to/app/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename
```

but in:

```
/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename
```

Try this instead:

```
has_attached_file :fichier,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
```

Comment: yes you're awesome! I was messing about with chmod danger until I got this